# Exercise 26 from Apostol's Calculus (p. 209, parts (c) & (d)))

Tags: calculus

This is a problem from Apostol's Calculus (p. 209 Ex. 26 (c) & (d)).
The problem is to find a function $f$ with a continuous second derivative $f''$ satisfying the following conditions:

> (c) $f''(x) > 0 \quad \text{for every } x, \qquad f'(0) = 1, \qquad f(x) \leq 100 \quad \text{for all } x > 0$.
>
> (d) $f''(x) > 0 \quad \text{for every } x, \qquad f'(0) = 1, \qquad f(x) \leq 100 \quad \text{for all } x < 0$.

So, for part (c) I do not think such a function can exist.  My proof is that $f''(x) > 0$ for every $x \implies f'(x)$ is increasing.  Since $f'(0) = 1$ this means $f'(x) > 1$ for $x > 0$.

By the mean value theorem we have $f(b) - f(0) = f'(c) (b)$ for some $c \in (0,b)$.  Since $f'(c) > 1$ for all $c \in (0,b)$ we have $f(b) > b + f(0)$ for any $b > 0$.  So, just choose $b > 100 + |f(0)|$ to obtain $f(b) > 100$ contradicting that $f(x) \leq 100$ for all $x > 0$.

Is this a sensible approach?  I feel like there should be a more straightforward way to get to this.

For (d) it seems to me that there should be some function to satisfy these restrictions (since for $x < 0$ we can certainly let $f$ take on arbitrarily large negative values).  It isn't clear to me how to systematically identify such a function though.

This problem comes from the exercises immediately following the statement and proofs of the first and second fundamental theorems of calculus, and a brief section on deducing properties of a function from its derivative; such as, a nonnegative derivative on an interval $\implies$ the function is increasing on the interval.

Comment: Your proof for c) looks correct at first glance. For d), how about $e^x$?

Comment: @AlexBecker Sorry, I don't know what is $e^x$ at this point... next chapter :)

Comment: You aren't familiar with the exponential function, or you don't know what it's derivative is?

Comment: We have not yet defined what is an exponential function or a logarithm.  Which is to say, I know what $e^x$ is, but it is not at my disposal yet.  We have power functions (for rational powers) and trigonometric functions.

Comment: @rar: Concerning (d): If you don't know about $\exp$ yet you could try a hyperbola with asymptotes $y=0$ and $x=1$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks for the suggestion.  That was the basic idea I needed to arrive at the answer below.  I had to play around with it a bit to get it to fit the given constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (c) I think the proof looks fine now.

For part(d):
Prompted by one of the comments, I propose the following piecewise definition that I believe meets the requirements of the question:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    x^2 + x + 1 & \text{if } x \geq 0,\\
    -1/(x-1) & \text{if } x \leq 0.
    \end{cases}$$

The graph of the function is given by:

[image]

Then we have $f''(x)$ exists and $>0$ for every $x$.  Further, the other required conditions are easily verified.

If anyone has a better solution, or a systematic way to approach finding such a function, I'd still like to see such an answer.  This was arrived at in a very ad hoc way (in that once I decided the vaguest properties each piece needed to have I just repeatedly adjusted the definition until it simultaneously met all of the requirements).